# jQuery UI slider in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I put this [slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range) in my project but in internet explorer 8 it doesn't work.

this is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 600,
        values: [ 100, 500 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - €" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - €" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In what version of IE does this not work? And what version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: What version of jQuery/jQueryUI are you using? Is is working on other browsers?

Comment: jquery-2.0.3 and jQuery UI - v1.10.3. i try also in IE10 but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Did you included **required files** ? They are at the bottom of the documentation page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/auaUY/ works fine at internet explorer but in my page doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two problems.

1) JQuery 2.X.X is not supported by IE8. You must use JQuery 1.X.X.

2) I removed ui and event as parameters frokm the function called in slide, because it is the way jquery-ui examples are. I think it's for compatibility reasons, but the way that it was before should work on IE8 as well.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 600,
        values: [ 100, 500 ],
        slide: refreshValues
    });
});

var refreshValues = function() {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - €" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ));
}
```

Well, this will do the trick.